# Cutting part of line/string in shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, cut

I have the following line:

```
Jan 13, 2014 1:01:31 AM
```

I want to remove the seconds part of the line. The result should be:

```
Jan 13, 2014 1:01 AM
```

How can this be done ?

Comment: It would be better if you indicate how you are obtaining such line, because we could try to change the `date` output format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parameter expansion:

```
t='Jan 13, 2014 1:01:31 AM'
ampm=${t: -2}               # last two characters
echo "${t%:*} $ampm"        # remove everything after the last :
```

Comment: +1, this is the most efficient way unlike spawning other processes like sed.

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
s='Jan 13, 2014 1:01:31 AM'
sed 's/:[0-9]*\( [AP]M\)/\1/' <<< "$s"
Jan 13, 2014 1:01 AM
```

Answer (score 1):

you can give this a try:

```
sed 's/:[^:]* / /'
```

with your example:

```
kent$ (master|✚2) echo "Jan 13, 2014 1:01:31 AM"|sed 's/:[^:]* / /'
Jan 13, 2014 1:01 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, if your date command is gnu date which support -d option.

```
$ str="Jan 13, 2014 1:01:31 AM"

$ date -d "$str" +"%b %d, %Y %l:%M %p"

Jan 13, 2014  1:01 AM
```